# KeyError for csvdictreader() isn't working when parameter for a function column header

Tags: python, keyerror

This is my code and I keep getting a key error. I have already opened the file in my initializer code for my class but the problem is I keep getting KeyError for this file. I know it works when I open the file within the function but when I open it outside the function it doesn't work and I get a KeyError. Please let me know if you need the full code. I can't use pandas or any other modules for this except import csv. I know this would be easier with that :)

```
    def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
        '''calculates avg for the column determine by specific based off the filter parameters given by 
        filter, logic, threshold'''
        
        if isinstance(threshold, str):
            threshold = float(threshold)

       
        running_sum = 0
        running_count = 0
        
        for row in csv.DictReader(self.load_data):
            value = int(row[filter])
                
            if logic == 'lt' and value < threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gt' and value > threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'lte' and value <= threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gte' and value >= threshold:
                include = True
            else:
                include = False

            if include:
                running_sum += int(row[specific])
                running_count += 1

            
        return (round(running_sum / running_count,2))
```

the command is
`print(csv_data.calc_avg("Length_of_stay", filter="SOFA", logic="lt", threshold="15"))`

the error I get is :

```
    value = int(row[filter])
KeyError: 'SOFA'
```

```
Sample Data:

RecordID SAPS-I SOFA    Length_of_stay  
132539    6      1         5    
132540    16     8         8    
132541    21     11       19    
132545    17     2         4    
132547    14     11        6    
132548    14     4         9    
132551    19     8         6    
132554    11     0        17
```

Full code:

```
class HWReader():
    
    def __init__(self, load_data):
        '''initializer that sets filename as a parameter that can be used within all functions'''
        
        self.load_data = open(load_data, "r")
        
    def get_saps(self, record_name):
        '''finds the saps score for a record name'''
        
        for row in csv.DictReader(self.load_data, delimiter = ','):
            if row['RecordID'] == record_name:
                return (row['SAPS-I'])

    def calc_avg(self, specific, filter, logic, threshold):
        '''calculates avg for the column determine by specific based off the filter parameters given by 
        filter, logic, threshold'''
        
        if isinstance(threshold, str):
            threshold = float(threshold)

        avg_file = csv.DictReader(self.load_data)

        running_sum = 0
        running_count = 0
        
        for row in avg_file:
            value = int(row[filter])
                
            if logic == 'lt' and value < threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gt' and value > threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'lte' and value <= threshold:
                include = True
            elif logic == 'gte' and value >= threshold:
                include = True
            else:
                include = False

            if include:
                running_sum += int(row[specific])
                running_count += 1

            
        return (round(running_sum / running_count,2))
```

Comment: Where is the defination of `self.load_data`?

Comment: I went ahead and added the full code, self.load_data is ```self.load_data = open(load_data, "r")```

Comment: For me code is working perfectly, not getting any error.

Comment: Really? that is so weird, it keeps giving me that code error and I don't understand why it's happening.